# Restore listview(with header) position after loading more data in Android

Tags: android, listview, chat

I am working on a chat application where I need to restore the listview item position after loading more data from server. I am using reverse listview (android:stackFromBottom="true" android:transcriptMode="normal") with header viewand using the below code to save the postion
`firstVisibleItem = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); 
oldCount = mListAdapter.getCount(); 
View view = mListView.getChildAt(0); 
position = (view == null ? 0 : view.getBottom()- mListView.getPaddingBottom());`

and the below code to re-store position

```
mListView.setSelectionFromTop(firstVisibleItem + mListAdapter.getCount() - oldCount+1, position);
```

The restored position is not exactly same, it moves up by one item. How to consider the header view height here???

I have tried with

```
View view = mListView.getChildAt(1); 
View view = mListView.getChildAt(-1);
```

but same problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you need to do this because you are replacing the old adapter with a new one by calling `setAdapter` when you have the new data, even though the new data is just the old data + some new things.

If you don't replace the adapter but just change the data it holds (by simply adding items, for example), the `ListView` will behave as you want by default. To accomplish this, make sure you have a way to update the data in the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged` when you're done. Do these things on the UI thread to avoid sync issues with the `ListView`.

Comment: I am not replacing the adapter but only adding the data to arraylist and calling notifyDataSetChanged. If I remove the header view its working as expected but with the header view it jumps one item up.